# WCF XML structure - how to remove wrapper nodes?

Tags: xml, wcf

I am having trouble when using List objects:

```
[DataContract]
public class Recipe
{
        [DataMember(Name="Allergies")]
        public List<AllergyModel> Allergies { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]    
public class AllergyModel
{
    public string Allergy { get; set; }
}
```

How do I make the XML produced not include the AllergyModel node? When I come to read the Recipe parameter, the Allergies list property is null because in the original XML the structure does not have the AllergyModel node.

```
<Allergies>
    <a:AllergyModel>
        <a:Allergy>nuts</a:Allergy>
    </a:AllergyModel>
    <a:AllergyModel>
        <a:Allergy>wheat</a:Allergy>
    </a:AllergyModel>
</Allergies>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use custom collection instead:

```
[CollectionDataContract(Name = "Allergies", ItemName = "Allergy")]
public class AllergyList : List<string>
{
    ...
}
```

Use this collection instead of `List<AllergyModel>`. The important is that you can pass the name of the item in the custom collection.

Comment: Thanks, my structure is now
<Recipe><Allergies><a:Allergy>nuts</a:Allergy><a:Allergy>wheat</a:Allergy></Allergies>

But when I inspect public XElement SubmitRecipe(Recipe recipe)
recipe.Allergies has a count of 0, any ideas?

My sample is this (I am receiving simple data types, just not collections).

<Recipe>
 <Allergies>
  <Allergy>nuts</Allergy>
  <Allergy>wheat</Allergy>
 </Allergies>
</Recipe>

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the current problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use MessageContract attribute instead and set the IsWrapped parameter to false

Comment: Hi Kevin, just for my info, can you please tell me why messageContract was not suitable in your casE ?